# Fortify Scan Issue : Cross-Site Scripting: Persistent (Input Validation and Representation, Data Flow)

Tags: java, rest, xss

I have implemented rest api with all the CURD operations. when i run fortify scan, it shows cross-site scripting issue for all the CURD operation methods in controller. I don't have a web layer in my project. we are providing rest service for the consumer. I have tried multiple things online nothing works. Is their any way to fix this issues other than adding validation for the input and output data?
Here is the code for GET :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET}, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> getRecords(
    @RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) String firstName,
    @RequestParam(value = "lastName", required = false) String lastName,
    @RequestParam(value = "city", required = false) String city,
    @RequestHeader(value = "authorization") String authorization) {

    List<Object> resultList = null;
    if (isAuthorized(authorization)) {
        resultList = service.getRecords(firstName, lastName, city);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(resultList);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? 

As I have read about it. We should not trust any user input. So you have to validate firstName, lastName, city and also authorization header.

Since the hacker might change the header maliciously. I would try atleast to escape it using ```HtmlUtils.htmlEscape()``` method

But I bet you have already tried it right?

I would try using a security framework so you can avoid calling ```isAuthorized`` every time at the beginning of the method. This probably would fix a lot of security issue automatically for you